# Can you retrieve the name of an object when loading an OBJ with SCNScene

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, scenekit, wavefront

I have an OBJ file that I'm loading into an SCNScene on iOS 9. I'd like to get access to the names defined in the OBJ.

So, if this is part of my OBJ file:

```
mtllib 56a92621b57ee2536f92da79.mtl

o 56a9088c3e8fbb40a600000c
usemtl 56a9088c3e8fbb40a600000c
v 310.9375 -117.1875 0
v 140.625 -115.625 0
v 143.75 14.0625 0
v 304.6875 20.3125 0
v 310.9375 -117.1875 0
...
```

I want the values in the o lines. Is that possible?